# Versioning multiple configurations

Tags: semantic-versioning

I've been using [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) for a project I'm distributing with Nexus, and I've run into a conundrum. I need to release two different configurations for each version: Release and Debug. In general, the average consumer will use the Release artifact(s), but some will want/need the Debug artifact(s).

**How can I consistently version the artifact(s) so the Release configuration takes precedence over the Debug configuration?**

- I could add an identifier for the Debug configuration, but then pre-release versions have the wrong precedence.

  ```
  ✓) 1.0.0-debug       (Debug)  <  1.0.0       (Release)
  ×) 1.0.0-alpha.debug (Debug)  >  1.0.0-alpha (Release)
  ```
- I could use metadata, but then the precedence is the same.

  ```
  ×) 1.0.0+debug (Debug)  =  1.0.0         (Release)
  ×) 1.0.0+debug (Debug)  =  1.0.0+release (Release)
  ```

Perhaps I'm simply approaching this the wrong way. If so, what's the right approach? A separate artifact?

Comment: @Airhead, there are good reasons to distribute debug artifacts for various packages, particularly libraries, which is the primary use case for SemVer.

Answer (score 0):

First let us define some terminology. Most modern build systems have at least "Debug" and "Release" configurations for build output, but in SemVer terms, either of those types can be a "Release" version (X.0.0) or a "Prerelease" version (X.Y.Z-prereleaseTag). The same holds true for code coverage and profiling configurations as well.

A package may contain only one version of the product, but the number of configurations is potentially unlimited, so you can generally package all of your configurations in separate directories for a single version.

Example package layout:

```
MyLib.1.0.0
    Debug
        Docs
        Bin
        Include
    Release
        Docs
        Bin
        Include
```

The details are dependent on the package tooling you are using. Nuget and NPM both have their own standard layout conventions but allow you pretty much lay things out any way you want.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I understand what you're saying. Could you include an example? It sounds like multiple artifacts in Nexus.

Comment: @ricksmt, Example added.